# Probability of a range of binomial event counts

Tags: r

I'm doing some problems on R and I am stuck on one that reads:

> Given a binomial event with N=18 and p=.70, what is the probability of obtaining between 8 and 13 successful outcomes?

I know that in R you put in `dbinom(x=,size=,prob=)`, but my actual question is what code could I use for this specific type of problem?

Answer (score 6):

`dbinom` returns the probability that a particular number of events will occur, so you can just sum those probabilities for 8 through 13 events:

```
sum(dbinom(8:13, 18, .7))
# [1] 0.6612726
```

Alternately, `pbinom` returns the probability that that number or fewer events will occur, so you could use subtraction to compute the probability that between 8 and 13 events occurred:

```
pbinom(13, 18, .7) - pbinom(7, 18, .7)
# [1] 0.6612726
```